# Problems with a partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have a physical HDD partitioned in the following way:

1) Partition 1 = Ext4 - Linux (Ubuntu Studio 16.04 LTS) OS.

2) partition 2 = Swap Area.

3) Partition 3 = NTFS - My data (music, videos, images, documents, etc.)

4) Partition 4 = Not used (an old Windows OS area, but full empty, now).

All is working so fine, in this way.

The problem is when I try to resize the partition 3: There is no way to do it.

Even if I unmount it, and/or when I eliminate the partition 4.

In all modes, Gparted doesn't let me to increase the size of that partition.

I can reduce its size, but not to increase it; and this is what I want to do: to increase the size of the partition 3!

What is this? What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of your Gparted?

Comment: I uploaded an image of Gparted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NTFS partition (/dev/sda5) was created inside an extended partition (/dev/sda3), therefore in order to enlarge it you should first enlarge the extended partition.

Do the following steps:

1. delete /dev/sda4 partition (you said it doesn't contain important data, right?);
2. unmount /dev/sda5 partition;
3. enlarge /dev/sda3 partition (if you don't plan to install Windows in the future, enlarge it to the maximum available size, otherwise keep about 30-50 GB of free space);
4. enlarge /dev/sda5 partition.

Comment: BTW: Is there a way to put the /dev/sda5 partition out of the /dev/sda3 extended partition (without to lose data, of course)? ???

Answer (score 1):

If partition #3 is only data, can you copy it to another place, delete both #3 and #4, then recreate and format a new partition? Is safer for your data.

Comment: I think I could do it. But... Isn't there another way? ???

Comment: I can't comment the other answer, so here he goes: you can't remove an extended partition directly. In you case you must shrink both sda5 and sda3, enlarge and format sda4 w/ NTFS, copy data from sda5->sda4, then remove both sda5+sda3 and finally enlarge the new NTFS partition. Always remember to backup your data in such operations ;)